# How do i separate my array strings delimiter (|) using implode function of php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I separate my array strings delimiter (|) using the implode function of PHP something like the below String

> |Java||PHP||Bootstrap||HTML||CSS|

Actually, I am using a double delimiter to differentiate tags like SQL and MySQL because  `LIKE "%sql%"` will return `MySQL` results as well. Should be `LIKE "%|sql|%"`

**What I have tried:**

```
$array_service_offer = array();
if (isset($_POST['service_offer'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['service_offer'] as $selectedOption) {
        array_push($array_service_offer, $selectedOption);
    }
    //$service_offer = implode(',',$array_service_offer);
    $service_offer = '|' . implode('||', $array_service_offer) . '|';
} else {
    $service_offer = "";
}
```

Comment: And that did not work? What did you get from that implode?

Comment: With your current code, you push it to the array before setting the value. So the first iteration will be empty, and the last will be missing in your `$service_offer` array.

Comment: After array_push what you get in $array_service_offer array?

Comment: `implode('||', $_POST['service_offer'])`, you don't need copy a new array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to @Qirel comment, I would also recommend to use `$array_service_offer[] = $selectedOption;` instead of `array_push($array_service_offer, $selectedOption);`

now for separation, there are several solutions.

One solution is that:
1- to remove first and last | character (it is like trimming)
2- to explode the trimmed string using || delimiter

for that you may use the following code:

```
$service_offer_trimmed = preg_replace("~(^\|)|(\|$)~", "", $service_offer);
$service_offer_array = explode('||', $service_offer_trimmed);
```

The other solution is to use straight forward **preg_replace** function to separate the string. the command follows:

```
$service_offer_array = preg_split("~(^\|)|(\|\|)|(\|$)~", $service_offer, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

And one more professional solution is that to store your data in database in **JSON** format rather than delimited code and then when you need to search in your database you may use MySql **JSON_CONTAINS** function rather than **LIKE** command.
I have not personally made a performance check on both two solutions but if it not a big database, then it is not a big concern as well.

Therefore, you initial code to get the data and store it into the database will be:

```
$array_service_offer = array();
if (isset($_POST['service_offer'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['service_offer'] as $selectedOption) {
        $array_service_offer[] = $selectedOption;
    }
}
// $json_service_offer will be saved to the database 
$json_service_offer = json_encode($array_service_offer);
```

the manual on how to use **JSON_CONTAINS** is in the following link:
[12.17.3 Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

Comment: My comment was not about using `array_push($array, ..)` vs `$array[] = ...`. It was the order of execution. Whichever method of pushing to the array is primarily opinion based, and both is valid.